# Convert relative to absolute links using jsoup

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to clean a html page, the problem is that when I save the html locally, the images do not show because they are all relative links.

Here's some example code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class so2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String html = "<html><head><title>The Title</title></head>"
                  + "<body><p><a href=\"/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif\" target=\"_blank\"><img width=\"437\" src=\"/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif\" height=\"418\" class=\"documentimage\"></a></p></body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,"https://whatever.com"); // baseUri seems to be ignored??

        System.out.println(doc);        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>The Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><a href="/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif" target="_blank"><img width="437" src="/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif" height="418" class="documentimage"></a></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

The output still shows the links as `a href="/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif"`.

I would like it to convert them to `a href="http://whatever.com/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif"`

Can anyone show me how to get jsoup to convert all the links to absolute links?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select all the links and transform their hrefs to absolute using `Element.absUrl()`

Example in your code:

EDIT (added processing of images)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String html = "<html><head><title>The Title</title></head>"
              + "<body><p><a href=\"/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif\" target=\"_blank\"><img width=\"437\" src=\"/data/abstract/ash/2014/5/9/Paper_69295_abstract_120490_0.gif\" height=\"418\" class=\"documentimage\"></a></p></body></html>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,"https://whatever.com"); 

    Elements select = doc.select("a");
    for (Element e : select){
        // baseUri will be used by absUrl
        String absUrl = e.absUrl("href");
        e.attr("href", absUrl);
    }

    //now we process the imgs
    select = doc.select("img");
    for (Element e : select){
        e.attr("src", e.absUrl("src"));
    }

    System.out.println(doc);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the href, but how would I do it for the img src?

Comment: well, you can do the same, select the imgs and transform the src attribute, I'm going to update the example...